# Check if the string is number is decimal or integer without using contains comma or dot

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, decimal, c#-8.0

I am trying to find if the string value is number and then check it is  decimal or an integer. Based on it we invoke certain logic

```
string value ="1,537"; // Value contains comma as it uses a Swedish culture sv-SE
```

```
if (decimal.TryParse(value, out var eval)) // First check if it is a number
{
    bool isWholeNumber = Math.Floor(decimal.Parse(value)) == decimal.Parse(value);
}
```

The problem with the above logic is **it treats "1,00" as Integer** and ran into integer logic

> As a work around I can check if the string contains ",".  But I feel
> its not a better way as the culture can be changed by user at any
> time.

Is there a better way to check this out?

[OneIDE Fiddle](https://ideone.com/mRZSjA)

Output as of now

```
The value 1,000 is integer True // This is wrong
The value 1,4500 is integer False
The value 1 is integer True
```

Comment: huum? `if (decimal.TryParse(value, out var eval))` returns true for `1.00`, doesn't it?

Comment: welll, you're checking if the parsed decimal a _whole number_ - not if the input has decimal places.... but have you thought about using `int.TryParse`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes it returned true for 1,00

Comment: Is the input strings _always_ from a system with a Swedish locale? `decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE"), out var eval)` should do the trick

Comment: @FranzGleichmann int.TryParse will parsed `2,350 to 2` without failure

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen the current culture is set based on user settings. It can be en-US, en-GB, etc

Comment: @Developer [not for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6LXh2H) - could you provide a code sample to reproduce the behavior you're describing?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann added a fiddle link

Comment: @Developer your fiddle _does not_ contain any reference to `int.TryParse`.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann int.TryParse also works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I would use [NumberStyles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=net-6.0), using `NumberStyles.Integer` might let your input be sure as an only number.

```
decimal.TryParse(value,NumberStyles.Integer,CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("sv-SE"), out var eval)
```

[c# fiddle](https://ideone.com/gulQRW)

Comment: It works! How do we deal for different culture? Can we make this to work with invariant culture?

Comment: .net being an MS product uses en-us as its default for everything that hasn't been explicitly set, you can use System.Globalization.CurrentCulture  to get the current culture

Comment: @Developer yes it might be work because we set the rule by  `NumberStyles` https://ideone.com/gulQRW